# Not found on acceleator - Apache Traffic Server

Tags: server, apache-traffic-server

I have installed Apache Traffic Server and configured records.config using:

```
CONFIG proxy.config.http.cache.http INT 1
CONFIG proxy.config.reverse_proxy.enabled INT 1
CONFIG proxy.config.url_remap.remap_required INT 1
CONFIG proxy.config.url_remap.pristine_host_hdr INT 1
CONFIG proxy.config.http.server_ports STRING 8080 8080:ipv6
```

I have also added a remap.config line cause I read it is essential:

```
regex_map http://(.*)/ http://localhost:80/
```

But when I try to access to localhost:8080, I get the output:

**Not Found on Accelerator**

*Description: Your request on the specified host was not found. Check the location and try again*

Why can I access to the server? I have followed the installation guide...

EDIT: Curl

```
curl localhost:8080
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Not Found on Accelerator</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black">
<H1>Not Found on Accelerator</H1>
<HR>

<FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
Description: Your request on the specified host was not found.
Check the location and try again.
</B></FONT>
<HR>
</BODY>
```

Comment: Can you pot the curl you are trying?  Btw this would be the same: map / http://localhost:80/

Comment: I edited it to post it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today. I figured it was caused by file permissions. Basically, trafficserver user had no write access to /etc/trafficserver folder (on Debian) and its content. I have changed ownership to trafficserver and now all working okay.

Take ownership recursively run the below in /etc:

```
chown -R trafficserver:trafficserver trafficserver
```

Also make sure Remap set to 0 in /etc/trafficserver/records.config

```
CONFIG proxy.config.url_remap.remap_required INT 0
```

> Set this variable to 1 if you want Traffic Server to serve requests only from origin servers listed in the mapping rules of the remap.config file. If a request does not match, then the browser will receive an error.

Comment: You should explain how to do this

Comment: Added some explanation